# How to simulate drop-down form in Delphi?

Tags: windows, shell, delphi, drop-down-menu, delphi-xe6

How can i create a *"drop-down"* window using Delphi?

Everything beyond this point is research effort; and is in no way related to the answer.

## Research Effort

Making a proper drop-down requires a lot of pieces to carefully work together. I assume people don't like the difficult question, and would rather i asked seven separate questions; each one addressing one tiny piece of the problem. Everything that follows is my *research effort* into solving the deceptively simple problem.

---

Note the defining characteristics of a drop-down window:

[image]

- **1.** The drop-down extends outside it's *"owner"* window
- **2.** The *"owner"* window keeps focus; the drop-down never steals focus
- **3.** The drop-down window has a drop-shadow

This is the Delphi variation of the same question i asked about in WinForms:

- [How to simulate a drop-down window in WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661670/how-to-simulate-a-drop-down-window-in-winforms)

The answer in WinForms was to use the [`ToolStripDropDown class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It is a helper class that turns any form into a drop-down.

### Lets do it in Delphi

I will start by creating a gaudy dropdown form, that serves as the example:

[image]

Next i will drop a button, that will be the thing i click to make the drop-down appear:

[image]

And finally i will wire-up some initial code to show the form where it needs to be in the **OnClick**:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; 
      Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
    frmPopup: TfrmPopup;
    pt: TPoint;
begin
    frmPopup := TfrmPopup.Create(Self);

    //Show the form just under, and right aligned, to this button
    pt := Self.ClientToScreen(Button1.BoundsRect.BottomRight);
    Dec(pt.X, frmPopup.ClientWidth);

    frmPopup.Show(Self, Self.Handle, pt);
end;
```

**Edit**: Changed it to **MouseDown** rather than **Click**. Click is incorrect, as the drop-down is shown without the need to click. One of the unresolved issues is how to *hide* a drop-down if the user mouse-downs the button again. But we'll leave that for the person who answers the question to solve. Everything in this question is research effort - not a solution.

And we're off:

[image]

### Now how to do it the right way?

First thing we notice right away is the lack of a drop-shadow. That's because we need to apply the `CS_DROPSHADOW` window style:

```
procedure TfrmPopup.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
const
    CS_DROPSHADOW = $00020000;
begin
    inherited CreateParams({var}Params);

    Params.WindowClass.Style := Params.WindowClass.Style or CS_DROPSHADOW;
end;
```

That fixes that:

[image]

## Focus Stealing

The next issue is that calling `.Show` on the popup causes it to steal focus (the title bar of the application indicates that it has lost focus). Sertac comes up with the solution to this.

- when the popup receives it's [`WM_Activate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) message indicating that it is receiving focus (i.e. `Lo(wParam) <> WA_INACTIVE`):
- send the parent form a [`WM_NCActivate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632633(v=vs.85).aspx)(True, -1) to indicate that it should draw itself like it still has focus

We handle the `WM_Activate`:

```
protected
   procedure WMActivate(var Msg: TWMActivate); message WM_ACTIVATE;
```

and the implementation:

```
procedure TfrmPopup.WMActivate(var Msg: TWMActivate);
begin
    //if we are being activated, then give pretend activation state back to our owner
    if (Msg.Active <> WA_INACTIVE) then
        SendMessage(Self.PopupParent.Handle, WM_NCACTIVATE, WPARAM(True), -1);

    inherited;
end;
```

So the owner window looks like it still has focus (who knows if that is the correct way to do it - it only *looks* like it still has focus):

[image]

### Rolling up

Fortunately, Sertac already solves the problem of how to dismiss the window whenever the user clicks away:

- when the popup receives it's [`WM_Activate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) message indicating that it is losing focus (i.e. `Lo(wParam) = WA_INACTIVE`):
- send the owner control a notification that we are rolling up
- Free the popup form

We add that to our existing `WM_Activate` handler:

```
procedure TfrmPopup.WMActivate(var Msg: TWMActivate);
begin
    //if we are being activated, then give pretend activation state back to our owner
    if (Msg.Active <> WA_INACTIVE) then
        SendMessage(Self.PopupParent.Handle, WM_NCACTIVATE, WPARAM(True), -1);

    inherited;

    //If we're being deactivated, then we need to rollup
    if Msg.Active = WA_INACTIVE then
    begin
        //TODO: Tell our owner that we've rolled up

        //Note: The parent should not be using rollup as the time to read the state of all controls in the popup.
        //      Every time something in the popup changes, the drop-down should give that inforamtion to the owner
        Self.Release; //use Release to let WMActivate complete
    end;
end;
```

### Sliding the dropdown

Dropdown controls use `AnimateWindow` to slide the drop-down down. From Microsoft's own `combo.c`:

```
if (!(TEST_EffectPUSIF(PUSIF_COMBOBOXANIMATION))
      || (GetAppCompatFlags2(VER40) & GACF2_ANIMATIONOFF)) {
   NtUserShowWindow(hwndList, SW_SHOWNA);
} 
else 
{
   AnimateWindow(hwndList, CMS_QANIMATION, (fAnimPos ? AW_VER_POSITIVE :
            AW_VER_NEGATIVE) | AW_SLIDE);
}
```

After checking if animations should be used, they use [`AnimateWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to show the window. We can use [`SystemParametersInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx) with **SPI_GetComboBoxAnimation**:

> Determines whether the slide-open effect for combo boxes is enabled. The *pvParam* parameter must point to a **BOOL** variable that receives **TRUE** for enabled, or **FALSE** for disabled.

Inside our newly consecrated `TfrmPopup.Show` method, we can check if *client area animations* are enabled, and call either `AnimateWindow` or `Show` depending on the user's preference:

```
procedure TfrmPopup.Show(Owner: TForm; NotificationParentWindow: HWND;
      PopupPosition: TPoint);
var
    pt: TPoint;
    comboBoxAnimation: BOOL;
begin
    FNotificationParentWnd := NotificationParentWindow;

    //We want the dropdown form "owned" by (i.e. not "parented" to) the OwnerWindow
    Self.Parent := nil; //the default anyway; but just to reinforce the idea
    Self.PopupParent := Owner; //Owner means the Win32 concept of owner (i.e. always on top of, cf Parent, which means clipped child of)
    Self.PopupMode := pmExplicit; //explicitely owned by the owner

    //Show the form just under, and right aligned, to this button
    Self.BorderStyle := bsNone;
    Self.Position := poDesigned;
    Self.Left := PopupPosition.X;
    Self.Top := PopupPosition.Y;

    if not Winapi.Windows.SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETCOMBOBOXANIMATION, 0, @comboBoxAnimation, 0) then
        comboBoxAnimation := False;

    if comboBoxAnimation then
    begin
        //200ms is the shell animation duration
        AnimateWindow(Self.Handle, 200, AW_VER_POSITIVE or AW_SLIDE or AW_ACTIVATE);
    end
    else
        inherited Show;
end;
```

**Edit**: Turns out there is `SPI_GETCOMBOBOXANIMATION` which should probably use over `SPI_GETCLIENTAREAANIMATION`. Which points to the depths of difficulty hidden behind the subtle *"How to simulate a drop-down"*. Simulating a drop-down requires a lot of stuff.

The problem is that Delphi forms pretty much fall over dead if you try to use `ShowWindow` or `AnimateWindow` behind their back:

[image]

**How to solve that?**

It's also odd that Microsoft itself uses either:

- `ShowWindow(..., SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE)`, or
- `AnimateWindow(...)` *(without `AW_ACTIVATE`)

to show the drop-down listbox *without* activation. And yet spying on a ComboBox with Spy++ i can see `WM_NCACTIVATE` flying around.

In the past people have simulated a slide window using repeated calls to change the `Height` of the drop-down form from a timer. Not only is this bad; but it also changes the size of the form. Rather than sliding down, the form grows down; you can see all the controls change their layout as the drop-down appears. No, having the drop-down form remain it's real size, but slide down is what is wanted here.

I know `AnimateWindow` and Delphi have never gotten along. And the question has been asked, a lot, long before Stackoverflow arrived. I even asked about it in 2005 on the newsgroups. But that can't stop me from asking again.

I tried to force my form to redraw after it animates:

```
AnimateWindow(Self.Handle, 200, AW_VER_POSITIVE or AW_SLIDE or AW_ACTIVATE);
Self.Repaint;
Self.Update;
Self.Invalidate;
```

But it doesn't work; it just sits there mocking me:

[image]

### Now showing again when i want to close-up

If a combobox is dropped down, and the user tries to **MouseDown** on the button, the real Windows ComboBox control does not simply show the control again, but instead hides it:

[image]

The drop-down also knows that it is currently *"dropped-down"*, which is useful so that it can draw itself as if it is in *"dropped down"* mode. What we need is a way to know that the drop-down is dropped down, and a way to know that the drop-down is no longer dropped down. Some kind of boolean variable:

```
private
   FDroppedDown: Boolean;
```

And it seems to me that we **need** to tell the host that we're closing up (*i.e. losing activation*). <strike>The host then needs to be responsible for destroying the popup.</strike> *(the host cannot be responsible for destroying the popup; it leads to an unresolvable race condition)*. So i create a message used to notify the owner that we're closing up:

```
const
   WM_PopupFormCloseUp = WM_APP+89;
```

**Note**: I don't know how people avoid message constant conflicts (especially since `CM_BASE` starts at $B000 and `CN_BASE` starts at $BC00).

Building on Sertac's activation/deactivation routine:

```
procedure TfrmPopup.WMActivate(var Msg: TWMActivate);
begin
    //if we are being activated, then give pretend activation state back to our owner
    if (Msg.Active <> WA_INACTIVE) then
        SendMessage(Self.PopupParent.Handle, WM_NCACTIVATE, WPARAM(True), -1);

    inherited;

    //If we're being deactivated, then we need to rollup
    if Msg.Active = WA_INACTIVE then
    begin
        //DONE: Tell our owner that we've rolled up
        //Note: We must post the message. If it is Sent, the owner
        //will get the CloseUp notification before the MouseDown that
        //started all this. When the MouseDown comes, they will think
        //they were not dropped down, and drop down a new one.
        PostMessage(FNotificationParentWnd, WM_PopupFormCloseUp, 0, 0);

        Self.Release; //use release to give WM_Activate a chance to return
    end;
end;
```

And then we have to change our **MouseDown** code to understand that the drop-down is still there:

```
procedure TForm3.Edit1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
    frmPopup: TfrmPopup;
    pt: TPoint;
begin
    //If we (were) dropped down, then don't drop-down again.
    //If they click us, pretend they are trying to close the drop-down rather than open a second copy
    if FDroppedDown then
    begin
        //And since we're receiving mouse input, we by defintion must have focus.
        //and since the drop-down self-destructs when it loses activation, 
        //it can no longer be dropped down (since it no longer exists)
        Exit;
    end;

    frmPopup := TfrmPopup.Create(Self);

    //Show the form just under, and right aligned, to this button
    pt := Self.ClientToScreen(Edit1.BoundsRect.BottomRight);
    Dec(pt.X, frmPopup.ClientWidth);

    frmPopup.Show(Self, Self.Handle, pt);
    FDroppedDown := True;
end;
```

### And i think that's it

Aside from the `AnimateWindow` conundrum, i may have been able use my research effort to solve all the problems i can think of in order to:

> Simulate a drop-down form in Delphi

Of course, this could all be for naught. It might turn out there's a VCL function:

```
TComboBoxHelper = class;
public
   class procedure ShowDropDownForm(...);
end;
```

In which case **that** would be the correct answer.

Comment: Only one window has the focus at one time. That's final. Use the keyboard to find out which one.

Comment: What I mean is, press 'down' in the last example, 'q-z' will be highlighted, not 'databinding' - the listview does not have the focus.

Comment: Dupe for the question in title: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178494/how-to-show-a-window-that-acts-like-a-popup-menu

Comment: @SertacAkyuz The interesting thing is that it's still Explorer (or in the case of a combobox, the form that contains the combobox). Whereas when i *show* form, it gets focus.

Comment: A *focused* (short for 'keyboard focus', like used in documentation of `WM_SETFOCUS`) window is defined as the window that receives keyboard input. Either you're wrong about your observations, or you use *focus* to mean a different thing.

Comment: @Sertac Ian means that the parent form looses active state, as can be seen by the inactive border color. (At)Ian This means that the dropdown form isn't a child of the parent form. By default, only one Delphi form can be active, so you have to try Windows.SetParent or something alike to make the dropdownform a child of the parent form.

Comment: @NGLN - I believe the solution, then, would involve making the *parent* form draw in a fake activation state, like I linked in a comment. Menu windows, combo lists etc. does not become a child.

Comment: @Ian - If you can confirm your question is a duplicate of the one I linked, we can close it as such. Otherwise you might try to expand on how different it is.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I've been using the insights in the linked question to solve the next issue. But there's still a number of issues related to simulating a drop-down that i have to work through. I was going to let the question it; hoping for someone knowing the answer to find it.

Comment: @Ian - Without specifics of those issues you may have a hard time finding solutions.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I'm editing the question as we speak. It takes an hour or so to do all the pretty screenshots, linking to MSDN documentation, citing sources, etc!

Comment: Not sure why the down votes, you're putting a lot of effort into this and have a clear goal.

Comment: @David - This is a very poor question which only asks for the non-existent VCLs all-in-one drop-down solution, with a lot of irrelevant side stories too. If the question didn't ask that, the asker would already accept, or at least comment on, the answer that provides the reason and the solution to the failing part that's stated in the question. At least that would be the reason for my down vote, currently the 3rd one.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz The question was "How to create a drop-down", not "How to solve the limited set of problems i have encountered so far in my attempts to show research effort". I was deliberate when i phrased the question, "How to simulate a drop-down form in Delphi"; because i knew how difficult it would be, and how my question could never encompass all the problems likely to be encountered in solving that problem. I agree that i should be allowed to ask *"How to create a drop-down in Delphi?" and leave it at that. But people tend to get grumpy and would close that question without reason.

Comment: @Ian - *" .. "How to create a drop-down", not "How to solve the limited set of problems i have encountered so far in my attempts to show research effort" ... "* - They are one and the same question, you put all the pieces together, as I stated in my answer now. To expect one to do them all here is, well, IMO too broad....

Comment: ... besides, there's no one size fits all solution. Some will want the first outside click to be eaten, like a combobox does, some otherwise, like a menu. Some will want it to be resizable, some will want an animation when closing. Some will want to reuse the drop-down instance, some will create each time it's rolled. It is very likely that you will want to lex out of shape the all-in-one solution, if anyone ever posts one.

Comment: If i ever have the question, *"How to simulate a menu window in Delphi"* that will be a separate question. Granted, a lot of code from this answer could be salvaged; but fundamentally it is a different question.

Comment: @Ian - They are not very much distinct, the case discussed on this page rather acts like a menu. You can't click a button on a form when a combo list is dropped down, the first click on the form is just eaten. Try it..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the bottom of `procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);` you call  `frmPopup.Show;` change that to `ShowWindow(frmPopup.Handle, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);` and after that you need to call `frmPopup.Visible := True;` else the components on the form won't show

So the new procedure looks like this:

```
uses
  frmPopupU;

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  frmPopup: TfrmPopup;
  pt: TPoint;
begin
  frmPopup := TfrmPopup.Create(Self);
  frmPopup.BorderStyle := bsNone;

  //We want the dropdown form "owned", but not "parented" to us
  frmPopup.Parent := nil; //the default anyway; but just to reinforce the idea
  frmPopup.PopupParent := Self;

  //Show the form just under, and right aligned, to this button
  frmPopup.Position := poDesigned;
  pt := Self.ClientToScreen(Button1.BoundsRect.BottomRight);
  Dec(pt.X, frmPopup.ClientWidth);
  frmPopup.Left := pt.X;
  frmPopup.Top := pt.Y;

  //  frmPopup.Show;
  ShowWindow(frmPopup.Handle, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
  //Else the components on the form won't show
  frmPopup.Visible := True;
end;
```

But this won't prevent you popup from stealing focus. Inorder for preventing that, you need to override the `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` event in your popup form

```
type
  TfrmPopup = class(TForm)
...
    procedure WMMouseActivate(var Message: TWMMouseActivate); message WM_MOUSEACTIVATE;
...
  end;
```

And the implementation

```
procedure TfrmPopup.WMMouseActivate(var Message: TWMMouseActivate);
begin
  Message.Result := MA_NOACTIVATE;
end;
```

I've decided to play arround with your popup window: The first thing I added was a close button. Just a simple TButton which in its onCLick Event calls Close:

```
procedure TfrmPopup.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;
```

But that would only hide the form, in order for freeing it I added a `OnFormClose` event:

```
procedure TfrmPopup.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;
```

Then finally I thought it would be funny to add a resize function

I did that by overriding the `WM_NCHITTEST` Message :

```
procedure TfrmPopup.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest);
const
  EDGEDETECT = 7; //adjust to suit yourself
var
  deltaRect: TRect; //not really used as a rect, just a convenient structure
begin
  inherited;

  with Message, deltaRect do
  begin
    Left := XPos - BoundsRect.Left;
    Right := BoundsRect.Right - XPos;
    Top := YPos - BoundsRect.Top;
    Bottom := BoundsRect.Bottom - YPos;

    if (Top < EDGEDETECT) and (Left < EDGEDETECT) then
      Result := HTTOPLEFT
    else if (Top < EDGEDETECT) and (Right < EDGEDETECT) then
      Result := HTTOPRIGHT
    else if (Bottom < EDGEDETECT) and (Left < EDGEDETECT) then
      Result := HTBOTTOMLEFT
    else if (Bottom < EDGEDETECT) and (Right < EDGEDETECT) then
      Result := HTBOTTOMRIGHT
    else if (Top < EDGEDETECT) then
      Result := HTTOP
    else if (Left < EDGEDETECT) then
      Result := HTLEFT
    else if (Bottom < EDGEDETECT) then
      Result := HTBOTTOM
    else if (Right < EDGEDETECT) then
      Result := HTRIGHT;
  end;
end;
```

So finally I've ended up with this :

```
unit frmPopupU;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TfrmPopup = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure WMMouseActivate(var Message: TWMMouseActivate); message WM_MOUSEACTIVATE;
    procedure WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest); message WM_NCHITTEST;
  public
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TfrmPopup }

procedure TfrmPopup.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

procedure TfrmPopup.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
const
  CS_DROPSHADOW = $00020000;
begin
  inherited CreateParams({var}Params);
  Params.WindowClass.Style := Params.WindowClass.Style or CS_DROPSHADOW;
end;

procedure TfrmPopup.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;

procedure TfrmPopup.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoubleBuffered := true;
  BorderStyle := bsNone;
end;

procedure TfrmPopup.WMMouseActivate(var Message: TWMMouseActivate);
begin
  Message.Result := MA_NOACTIVATE;
end;

procedure TfrmPopup.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest);
const
  EDGEDETECT = 7; //adjust to suit yourself
var
  deltaRect: TRect; //not really used as a rect, just a convenient structure
begin
  inherited;

  with Message, deltaRect do
  begin
    Left := XPos - BoundsRect.Left;
    Right := BoundsRect.Right - XPos;
    Top := YPos - BoundsRect.Top;
    Bottom := BoundsRect.Bottom - YPos;

    if (Top < EDGEDETECT) and (Left < EDGEDETECT) then
      Result := HTTOPLEFT
    else if (Top < EDGEDETECT) and (Right < EDGEDETECT) then
      Result := HTTOPRIGHT
    else if (Bottom < EDGEDETECT) and (Left < EDGEDETECT) then
      Result := HTBOTTOMLEFT
    else if (Bottom < EDGEDETECT) and (Right < EDGEDETECT) then
      Result := HTBOTTOMRIGHT
    else if (Top < EDGEDETECT) then
      Result := HTTOP
    else if (Left < EDGEDETECT) then
      Result := HTLEFT
    else if (Bottom < EDGEDETECT) then
      Result := HTBOTTOM
    else if (Right < EDGEDETECT) then
      Result := HTRIGHT;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Hope you can use it.

## Full and functional code

The following unit was tested only in Delphi 5 (emulated support for `PopupParent`). But beyond that, it does everything a drop-down needs. Sertac solved the `AnimateWindow` problem.

```
unit DropDownForm;

{
    A drop-down style form.

    Sample Usage
    =================

        procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
        var
            pt: TPoint;
        begin
            if FPopup = nil then
                FPopup := TfrmOverdueReportsPopup.Create(Self);
            if FPopup.DroppedDown then //don't drop-down again if we're already showing it
                Exit;

            pt := Self.ClientToScreen(SmartSpeedButton1.BoundsRect.BottomRight);
            Dec(pt.X, FPopup.Width);

            FPopup.ShowDropdown(Self, pt);
        end;

    Simply make a form descend from TDropDownForm.

        Change:
            type
                TfrmOverdueReportsPopup = class(TForm)

        to:
            uses
                DropDownForm;

            type
                TfrmOverdueReportsPopup = class(TDropDownForm)
}

interface

uses
    Forms, Messages, Classes, Controls, Windows;

const
    WM_PopupFormCloseUp = WM_USER+89;

type
    TDropDownForm = class(TForm)
    private
        FOnCloseUp: TNotifyEvent;
        FPopupParent: TCustomForm;
        FResizable: Boolean;
        function GetDroppedDown: Boolean;
{$IFNDEF SupportsPopupParent}
        procedure SetPopupParent(const Value: TCustomForm);
{$ENDIF}
    protected
        procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
        procedure WMActivate(var Msg: TWMActivate); message WM_ACTIVATE;
        procedure WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest); message WM_NCHITTEST;

        procedure DoCloseup; virtual;

        procedure WMPopupFormCloseUp(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_PopupFormCloseUp;

{$IFNDEF SupportsPopupParent}
        property PopupParent: TCustomForm read FPopupParent write SetPopupParent;
{$ENDIF}
  public
        constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;

        procedure ShowDropdown(OwnerForm: TCustomForm; PopupPosition: TPoint);
        property DroppedDown: Boolean read GetDroppedDown;
        property Resizable: Boolean read FResizable write FResizable;

        property OnCloseUp: TNotifyEvent read FOnCloseUp write FOnCloseUp;
  end;

implementation

uses
    SysUtils;

{ TDropDownForm }

constructor TDropDownForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
    inherited;

    Self.BorderStyle := bsNone; //get rid of our border right away, so the creator can measure us accurately
    FResizable := True;
end;

procedure TDropDownForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
const
    SPI_GETDROPSHADOW = $1024;
    CS_DROPSHADOW = $00020000;
var
    dropShadow: BOOL;
begin
    inherited CreateParams({var}Params);

    //It's no longer documented (because Windows 2000 is no longer supported)
    //but use of CS_DROPSHADOW and SPI_GETDROPSHADOW are only supported on XP (5.1) or newer
    if (Win32MajorVersion > 5) or ((Win32MajorVersion = 5) and (Win32MinorVersion >= 1)) then
    begin
        //Use of a drop-shadow is controlled by a system preference
        if not Windows.SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETDROPSHADOW, 0, @dropShadow, 0) then
            dropShadow := False;

        if dropShadow then
            Params.WindowClass.Style := Params.WindowClass.Style or CS_DROPSHADOW;
    end;

{$IFNDEF SupportsPopupParent} //Delphi 5 support for "PopupParent" style form ownership
    if FPopupParent <> nil then
        Params.WndParent := FPopupParent.Handle;
{$ENDIF}
end;

procedure TDropDownForm.DoCloseup;
begin
    if Assigned(FOnCloseUp) then
        FOnCloseUp(Self);
end;

function TDropDownForm.GetDroppedDown: Boolean;
begin
    Result := (Self.Visible);
end;

{$IFNDEF SupportsPopupParent}
procedure TDropDownForm.SetPopupParent(const Value: TCustomForm);
begin
    FPopupParent := Value;
end;
{$ENDIF}

procedure TDropDownForm.ShowDropdown(OwnerForm: TCustomForm; PopupPosition: TPoint);
var
    comboBoxAnimation: BOOL;
    i: Integer;

const
    AnimationDuration = 200; //200 ms
begin
    //We want the dropdown form "owned" by (i.e. not "parented" to) the OwnerForm
    Self.Parent := nil; //the default anyway; but just to reinforce the idea
    Self.PopupParent := OwnerForm; //Owner means the Win32 concept of owner (i.e. always on top of, cf Parent, which means clipped child of)
{$IFDEF SupportsPopupParent}
    Self.PopupMode := pmExplicit; //explicitely owned by the owner
{$ENDIF}

    //Show the form just under, and right aligned, to this button
//  Self.BorderStyle := bsNone; moved to during FormCreate; so can creator can know our width for measurements
    Self.Position := poDesigned;
    Self.Left := PopupPosition.X;
    Self.Top := PopupPosition.Y;

    //Use of drop-down animation is controlled by preference
    if not Windows.SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETCOMBOBOXANIMATION, 0, @comboBoxAnimation, 0) then
        comboBoxAnimation := False;

    if comboBoxAnimation then
    begin
        //Delphi doesn't react well to having a form show behind its back (e.g. ShowWindow, AnimateWindow).
        //Force Delphi to create all the WinControls so that they will exist when the form is shown.
        for i := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do
        begin
            if Controls[i] is TWinControl and Controls[i].Visible and
                    not TWinControl(Controls[i]).HandleAllocated then
            begin
                TWinControl(Controls[i]).HandleNeeded;
                SetWindowPos(TWinControl(Controls[i]).Handle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                        SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOZORDER or SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
            end;
        end;
        AnimateWindow(Self.Handle, AnimationDuration, AW_VER_POSITIVE or AW_SLIDE or AW_ACTIVATE);
        Visible := True; // synch VCL
    end
    else
        inherited Show;
end;

procedure TDropDownForm.WMActivate(var Msg: TWMActivate);
begin
    //If we are being activated, then give pretend activation state back to our owner
    if (Msg.Active <> WA_INACTIVE) then
        SendMessage(Self.PopupParent.Handle, WM_NCACTIVATE, WPARAM(True), -1);

    inherited;

    //If we're being deactivated, then we need to rollup
    if Msg.Active = WA_INACTIVE then
    begin
        {
            Post a message (not Send a message) to oursleves that we're closing up.
            This gives a chance for the mouse/keyboard event that triggered the closeup
            to believe the drop-down is still dropped down.
            This is intentional, so that the person dropping it down knows not to drop it down again.
            They want clicking the button while is was dropped to hide it.
            But in order to hide it, it must still be dropped down.
        }
        PostMessage(Self.Handle, WM_PopupFormCloseUp, WPARAM(Self), LPARAM(0));
    end;
end;

procedure TDropDownForm.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest);
var
    deltaRect: TRect; //not really used as a rect, just a convenient structure
    cx, cy: Integer;
begin
    inherited;

    if not Self.Resizable then
        Exit;

    //The sizable border is a preference
    cx := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZEFRAME);
    cy := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSIZEFRAME);

    with Message, deltaRect do
    begin
        Left := XPos - BoundsRect.Left;
        Right := BoundsRect.Right - XPos;
        Top := YPos - BoundsRect.Top;
        Bottom := BoundsRect.Bottom - YPos;

        if (Top < cy) and (Left < cx) then
            Result := HTTOPLEFT
        else if (Top < cy) and (Right < cx) then
            Result := HTTOPRIGHT
        else if (Bottom < cy) and (Left < cx) then
            Result := HTBOTTOMLEFT
        else if (Bottom < cy) and (Right < cx) then
            Result := HTBOTTOMRIGHT
        else if (Top < cy) then
            Result := HTTOP
        else if (Left < cx) then
            Result := HTLEFT
        else if (Bottom < cy) then
            Result := HTBOTTOM
        else if (Right < cx) then
            Result := HTRIGHT;
    end;
end;

procedure TDropDownForm.WMPopupFormCloseUp(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
    //This message gets posted to us.
    //Now it's time to actually closeup.
    Self.Hide;

    DoCloseup; //raise the OnCloseup event *after* we're actually hidden
end;

end.
```

Comment: Showing the form in an inactive state doesn't it prevent from getting active in future. Does this solution prevent the parent form from getting inactive when the user clicks somewhere in the popup form?

Comment: I haven't tested that. I I won't have time to do so until later

Comment: @NGLN I've updated the answer. Perhaps we should cleanup theese messages?

Comment: In the next iteration of code i moved from a `Click` to a `MouseDown`. Because in reality the user does not have to **click** a button; the drop-down appears right on mouse down. The next trick is how to make it *not* re-appear if i mouse-down on the button again. Sertac, in a related question, solved the activation and deactivation issue. I incorporated that code and updated the question.

Comment: @IanBoyd I solved the original question. Now you feel for changing it . And you are showing the popup in a diffrent way compared to what I've showed you. **I'll stop here**.

Comment: The question was *"How to create a drop-down"*, not *"how to solve the limited set of problems that i have encountered so far in my attempts to show research effort into how to create a drop-down"*. I was deliberate when i phrased the question, *"How to simulate a drop-down form in Delphi"*; because i knew how difficult it would be, and how my question could never encompass all the problems likely to be encountered in solving that problem.

Comment: @IanBoyd perhaps if you comment on my code I would put some more effort into your question. Bu so far I've only wasted my time

Comment: Well, i actually appreciated your work; and that you took the time to do it. I was trying to be helpful in pointing you towards Sertac's solution of the losing/gaining/losing problem (which looks to be internally how the Combobox does it as well). And while i don't have any immediate need for resizing the drop-down; it certainly will be useful for anyone else coming along to this question in the future.

Comment: `MA_NOACTIVATE` helps when you click directly on the popup form. But when you click on one of the controls on the form, the base form deactivates. This is not a working solution currently.

Comment: you could subclass the components on the form.

Comment: I you make me an example program of what you have so far I'll give it a try again

Comment: I ended up using your `WM_NCHitTest` code for resizing. As soon as i had the drop-down i realized i wanted to be able to resize the form. The only exception is that i used the user preferences of resizing border size ( `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZEFRAME)` and `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSIZEFRAME)`) rather than hard-coding `7` pixels. Nice work.

Comment: Cool @IanBoyd - So what do we have left before reaching the goal? Could you by any chance make me a minimum example? You could email me at jens@borrisholt.dk then we could publish he solution here afterwords.

Comment: Sorry, been writing code to actually populate it with real stuff (real work distractions). I'll append the final code into your answer. As a practical matter it turns out i couldn't use the form resizing. In order to have the `bsNone` form have a single pixel internal border, i had to have a panel inside panel. Windows sends the `WM_NCHITTEST` directly to the panel window procedures. And while i could have subclassed the two panels, a VirtualStringTree, and TWebBrowser, it was easier to go without. And besides, it was outside the scope of the question :)

Comment: The original post used `ShowWindow` with `SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE`, which was a dead end. @Ian, you'd rather post your own answer, the final solution has got very little with what was in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'll sound grumpy for this but this answer really deserves the -1 for it proposes and explains a non-working solution (`ShowWindow` with `SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE`, and handling `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE`) and at the same time includes a completely different final working solution.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz it wasn't me who added the "Full and functional code" part. So yes you are grumpy.

Comment: @Jens - Even without the additional code you have a wrong answer. If that's not what a down vote is for, what is?

Comment: This is a great piece of code for implementing a non-active form, I've been using this technique quite a long time. However, recently I run into an issue with Chinese input method - the form will cover the language input bar (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin_input_method). Any hint to solve that? I've spent one entire day without success, thanks.

Comment: thanks for the effort guys very detailed question, nice solution!

Comment: small recommendation: in the Create() save the ClientWidth+ClientHeight before setting the BorderStyle and restore after that, otherwise the form ClientArea will be bigger than it was in design-time.

Comment: Any chance to draw a simple border around the form ? The left and the top edges has no border... I try puting all the form content in a TPanel and set the BevelKing to bvFlat, but has no effect...

Answer (score 5):

> *How can i create a "drop-down" window using Delphi?*

You put together all the bits and pieces you have summarized, there is no one VCL class/function that would produce a drop down form.

There are a few points to mention in your research though.

First, you're confusing activation with focus. Focus is not preserved in the calling form when another window pops in front of it, activation is - or it seems that way. Focus is where keyboard input goes, it is obviously on either the popped/dropped window or on a control in it.

Your problem with controls not showing with `AnimateWindow` is that, VCL does not create underlying native (OS) controls of `TWinControl`s until it is necessary (non-wincontrols are not a problem). As far as VCL is concerned, creating them is not normally necessary until they will be visible, which is when you set `Visible` of your form to true (or call `Show`), which you cannot since then there will be no animation, unless of course you set `visible` after the animation.

This is also the missing requirement when you try to refresh your form:

```
AnimateWindow(Self.Handle, 200, AW_VER_POSITIVE or AW_SLIDE or AW_ACTIVATE);
Self.Repaint;
Self.Update;
Self.Invalidate;
```

Notice that in the above quote from the question, none of the calls fail. But there's nothing to paint, the form is not even *`visible`* yet.

Any means of forcing the controls to be created and making them visible will make your animation come alive.

```
...
if comboBoxAnimation then
begin
  for i := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do
    if Controls[i] is TWinControl and Controls[i].Visible and
        not TWinControl(Controls[i]).HandleAllocated then begin
      TWinControl(Controls[i]).HandleNeeded;
      SetWindowPos(TWinControl(Controls[i]).Handle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOZORDER or SWP_NOACTIVATE or
          SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    end;
  AnimateWindow(Handle, 200, AW_VER_POSITIVE or AW_SLIDE or AW_ACTIVATE);
  Visible := True; // synch VCL
end
else
  ...
```

This is just an example, showing the form off-screen or any other creative method could work equally well. Here, [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28702203/243614), I achieve the same by setting animated form's height to '0' before setting `visible` to true (I like the approach in this answer better though..).

Regarding not dropping again when the form is already dropped down, you don't have to post a message to the calling form for that. In fact don't do that, it requires unnecessary cooperation from the calling form. There will ever be only one instance to be dropped down, so you can use a global:

```
  TfrmPopup = class(TForm)
    ...
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FNotificationParentWnd: HWND;
    class var
      FDroppedDown: Boolean;
  protected
    ...


procedure TfrmPopup.Show(Owner: TForm; NotificationParentWindow: HWND;
  ...

  if not FDroppedDown then begin
      if comboBoxAnimation then begin

        // animate as above

        Visible := True; // synch with VCL
        FDroppedDown := True;
      end
      else
        inherited Show;
    end;
end;

procedure TfrmPopup.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDroppedDown := False;
end;
```